# anaconda installation problem

Tags: software-installation, python3, anaconda

I tried to install Anaconda using following commands:

```
bash Anaconda3-2018.12-Linux-ppc64le.sh
```

but after sometime it says :

```
Anaconda3 will now be installed into this location:
/home/sz97/anaconda3

  - Press ENTER to confirm the location
  - Press CTRL-C to abort the installation
  - Or specify a different location below

[/home/sz97/anaconda3] >>> 
PREFIX=/home/sz97/anaconda3
installing: python-3.7.1-h4134adf_7 ...
Anaconda3-2018.12-Linux-ppc64le.sh: line 377: /home/sz97/anaconda3/pkgs/python-3.7.1-h4134adf_7/bin/python: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

what is the problem?

Comment: Is your system architecture actually `ppc64le`?

Comment: My OS is 64 bit. I am using KUBUNTU 18.10

Comment: OK - but is it 64-bit little-endian PPC (ppc64le)? or is it the more common 64-bit Intel/AMD (x86_64) architecture?

Comment: Intel Core i3 x64

Comment: In that case, you need [Anaconda2-2018.12-Linux-x86_64.sh](https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda2-2018.12-Linux-x86_64.sh)